# CSS gradient don't disaaper by hovering

Tags: html, css

I want to create a gradient in the end of the of the link like this:

[image: gradient1]

The gradient should disappear when hovering over it.

My **HTML** code ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m6odm2wu/)):

```
<a href="#">https://<span class="txt">in Phrase Overview</span></a>
```

**CSS** code

```
.txt {
   padding: 12px 16px;
   color:blue;
   top:0;
   -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0 10px -2px #ffffff;
   box-shadow: -10px 0 10px -2px #ffffff;  
}

span:hover {    
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   box-shadow: none;  
}
```

But when I hover it, the gradient doesn't disappear:

[image: gradient2]

please, help me to check this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your style to this:

```
.txt{
  padding: 12px 16px;
  color:blue;
  top:0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0 10px -2px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 10px -2px #ffffff;  
}
a:hover span.txt{    
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;  
}
```